# Conectar SQL Server con Excel mediante autenticación de Windows

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012, macros

Estoy tratando de ejecutar la siguiente Macro, la cual funciona cuando hago referencia a un servidor con credenciales de usuario y contraseña, pero el problema sucede al querer utilizar la autenticación de windows, ya que es la forma donde accedo al SQL Server. Comprendo que hay otras opciones más manuales dentro de Excel, pero requiero que la consulta sea según el contenido de una celda, es por ello mi necesidad de manejarlo con Macros.

```
    Function ConectarSQL(Sql As String, TextBox As String)
Dim Columna, Fila
Dim Conect As Object

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Creamos un Objeto de Conexión

Set Conect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

' Especificamos la Conexión a utilizar

With frmSQLServer
    servidor = .txtServidor.Value
    Usuario = .txtUsuario.Value
    pass = .txtPass.Value
    base = .txtBase.Value
End With


Conexion = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
           "Password=" & pass & ";" & _
           "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
           "User ID=" & Usuario & ";" & _
           "Initial Catalog=" & base & ";" & _
           "Data Source=" & servidor

Conect.ConnectionString = Conexion

'Validación que verifica que los parámetros no estén vacíos
If Sql <> vbNullString And TextBox <> vbNullString Then

    'VARIABLE para el REC de ADO
    Dim RecordSet As Object

    'ABRIMOS la Conexión a la Base de Datos
    Conect.Open

    'CREAMOS un nuevo Objeto RecordSet
    Set RecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    'Ejecutamos el SQL para llamar al RecordSet
    RecordSet.Open Sql, Conect
    ' variables para los indices de las filas y columnas
    Columna = 0
    Fila = 0
```

Comment: Hola amigo si utilizaras la autenticación de windows ya no es necesario pasar un usuario y contraseña si no mas bein algo como esto Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase; Trusted_Connection=yes; remplazalo con lo tuyo y me dices saludos

Comment: Quedó así después del with: Conexion = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase; Trusted_Connection=yes"

Conect.ConnectionString = Conexion  

Pero no funcionó. ¿No conoces una forma de realizar una conexión de SQL Server con Excel y que en el "where" de la query haga referencia a una celda?, esto a modo de filtro.

Comment: Trata con este amigo "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
        "Data Source="your ServerName"; " & _
        "Initial Catalog=database name;" & _
        "Integrated Security=SSPI"